# Output is more extensive than Results window can remember so log capturing forgets to record

Tags: stata

I have an extensive Stata do-file that runs with no issues, but there is too much output to be all captured in the results window. I read up on log files to create a capture of the output, which works. This is the code I have at the beginning of my do-file:

```
______________________________________________*/
capture log close
clear

*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*SET THIS TO USE THE CORRECT DIRECTORY
local thisdir "C:\Users\my computer file" 
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cd "`thisdir'"

log using "STATAlogfile.txt", text append
```

The do file then runs successfully until the end where I have a `log close` and then get the output in the results window:

```
. 
. log close
no log file open
r(606);

end of do-file

r(606);
```

The log txt file when I look at it then only captures a small amount of the do-file (I assume as far as what can be fit within the memory of the Results window).
I was wondering how I can fix this: is it as simple as sticking in a bunch of log appends in the middle of my do-file to capture everything, or is there a different command that will make sure it continues throughout the whole do-file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow the assertions in the post title or body.

1. There is no sense in which the code "forgets" to do anything. It seems that it is you, the programmer, who forgot to include `log` commands where you now realise you needed them. That could happen to any experienced programmer too.
2. What goes in a log file is nothing to do with what is visible at any one time in the Results window. A log file is unlimited in size, subject to your computer memory.

If you can't copy and paste results retrospectively, then the only work-around is to fix your do-file code and run it again.

I think what underlies your question is a verbal misunderstanding of `capture`. `capture` as a Stata command is about eating an error if the following command fails. That is, `capture` ensures that Stata carries on when otherwise it would stop with an error message. It has nothing to do with capturing, in the sense of catching and recording, your output.

Spelling is Stata, not STATA, and has been since about 1985.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. I've been able what to figure out the problem is - I'd left a capture log close within the large do-file, while it's a silly mistake, at least it's an easy one to fix!